# VALIDATE CONSTRAINT sometimes validates, sometimes doesn't

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named base_types that contains this constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE public.base_types
    ADD CONSTRAINT base_type_gas_type_fk FOREIGN KEY (gas_type)
    REFERENCES public.gas_types (gas_type) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

And I have a table named alarm_history that contains five constraints, including this one:

```
ALTER TABLE public.alarm_history
    ADD CONSTRAINT alarm_history_device_fk FOREIGN KEY (device)
    REFERENCES public.bases (alarm_device) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

I am trying to convert a database from one that didn't bother with anything weird and useless like constraints into one that uses them.  I am beginning with this script:

```
delete from gas_types;
select conversion.convert_base_types();
alter table base_types validate constraint base_type_gas_type_fk;


select conversion.convert_alarm_history();
alter table alarm_history validate constraint alarm_history_base_fk;
alter table alarm_history validate constraint alarm_history_charge_fk;
alter table alarm_history validate constraint alarm_history_cooler_fk;
alter table alarm_history validate constraint alarm_history_device_fk;
alter table alarm_history validate constraint alarm_history_furnace_fk;
```

I duly get an error message telling me that the gas_type field in my new base_types record doesn't match anything in the gas_types table, since the gas_types table is empty.  But if I comment out the base_types commands, I get 18,000 nice, shiny new records in the alarm_history table, despite the fact that every single one of them violates at least one of that table's five foreign key constraints, since all of the tables those keys are referring to are empty.  I need to ensure that my converted data is consistent, and therefore I need to validate my constraints, but that's obviously not happening.  Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Since the constraints above are created as `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`, they are not checked until the DML statements (your delete statement) are committed or in your case you until you explicitly validate the constraint.

This is the normal and expected operation of an initially deferred deferrable constraint.

To change this functionality within your current transaction you can issue a [`SET CONSTRAINTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set-constraints.html) command to alter this:

```
SET CONSTRAINTS alarm_history_device_fk IMMEDIATE;
delete from gas_types;
```

Which should raise a foreign key violation alerting you earlier that you have data dependent on the records you are tying to delete.

Comment: I need the deferred constraints because later on I am going to be dealing with circular constraints.  But if you explained why I do not get a foreign key constraint violation on the alarm_history table, I did not understand it.  I want to keep the deferred constraint, but after the table is populated I want to validate the constraint.

Comment: Since I don't know what `select conversion.convert_base_types();` or `select conversion.convert_alarm_history();` do I can't tell you why you aren't getting the FK constraint violations, or even if you should, however, it's likely related to the deferred status of your constraints.  Deferred constraints aren't checked until the data manipulation statements (Inserts, updates, and/or deletes) are committed.